# How to convert L*a*b* to grayscale in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, colors, color-space, lab-color-space

I have already converted an `RGB` image into `La*b*` colorspace, but I want to convert it into gray scale. I'm not sure whether I can use `rgb2gray` or not.

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `L` channel of `Lab` colorspace is the grayscale part. Just use it as is. Using `rgb2gray` will not work as expected, since it expects that the three channels that you give to it as an input are from `RGB` colorspace.

Answer (score 5):

If you have an image in the CIELa*b* colorspace representation, you could just convert it back to RGB using `Lab2RGB`(can be found [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24010)) and then use the function `rgb2gray` to convert your image to grayscale.

Be aware that there is a difference in the grayscale image produced by `rgb2gray` and the `L`channel produced by `RGB2Lab`.

In Matlab, grayscale is simply achieved by

```
0.2989 * R + 0.5870 * G + 0.1140 * B
```

where the `L`is achieved via a way more complex manner ([see source code](https://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Research/Projects/CS/vision/bsds/code/Util/RGB2Lab.m)), hence gives a different result.

So choose wisely according to your needs or requirements!